# How to make an event that takes time nonblocking?

Tags: node.js, multithreading, dom-events, nonblocking

I was thinking - since node.js runs in single thread, what if I want to do some algorithmically difficult computation (`hard_and_complex_function()`), that has nothing to do with I/O but takes a LOT of time? Can I make it non-blocking? Isn't it a disadvantage compared to multi-threading technologies - where I can simply run it in a separate thread?

Answer (score 0):

While you are correct with regard to threads, you have at least two options that might address your problem at hand:

1. Use [process.nextTick()](http://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_nexttick_callback) to yield the CPU at appropriate points in the long computation.
2. Use a separate process (using [child_process](http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html) or [Cluster](http://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html)) to carry out your long computation.

You may also want, for future use, to take a look at Generators and `yield` coming in ES6.

Answer (score -1):

There is solution available for tacking long running application in Node.js. Have a look at below library :

https://github.com/xk/node-threads-a-gogo